# Issues installing Memcached

Tags: ubuntu, installation, memcached

I am facing issues installing memcaced on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04) after downloading it from [**here**](https://memcached.org/) .

When I try to extract the tar file, it shows the below error :

```
DaarioNaharis :~/Softwares/memcached$ tar zxvf memcached-1.4.25.tar.gz 

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I went through the [**docs**](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki) on the website, which wasn't of much help (Is it still actively maintained??). Need help in getting this installed.

Thank you.

Comment: well, that output pretty much simply means what it says. The file you're trying to uncompress is not in gzip format. So either your download is horribly broken, or it has the wrong extension and isn't a gzip'ed tar archive.

Comment: Have you checked the download was not corrupted? You could try downloading again, or verify the file against a hash from https://www.memcached.org/files/

Comment: I verified the hash, dunno if it's the correct way though, it shows a different one form what is mentioned on the website.

Comment: I calculated it using the sha1sum command :

**bf9e1fcf839dd6a15d6b68223308886bc8abae60  memcached-1.4.25.tar.gz**


On the website :
**sha1: 7fd0ba9283c61204f196638ecf2e9295688b2314**

Comment: Hi Marcus,

I understand that there is an issue with the file, which is pretty obvious, I am looking for help finding a solution.


This isn't off topic (You have voted so). There still appears to be an issue with the download link, and the soln suggested below appears to help solve it. This post might be helpful for other tyros as myself who are facing a similar issue.


I understand that you and other moderators are doing a good job maintaining content standards, but this **borders on over-moderation**. Do not dissuade others from answering if you feel this question is too basic for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, it can be inferred that the file you have downloaded is not in the gzip format. I faced the same issue a while ago.

Check the file extension type, which has some how been unzipped (Unzipped file put in the link / Some server setting??).

```
file memcached-1.4.25.tar.gz
memcached-1.4.25.tar.gz: tar archive
```

I renamed the file, and untarred it (Rename to memcached-1.4.25.tar), and it worked. Now try extracting it using the below :

```
tar -xvf memcached-1.4.25.tar
```

Since this contains the source files, install using the following, which can be found on the website docs :

```
./configure && make && make test && sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, and it worked!